# SQLAlchemy ошибка already has a primary mapper defined

Tags: python, python-3.5, sqlalchemy

Делаю первые шаги с sqlalchemy. В строке `mapper(User, users_table)` происходит ошибка.

```
{"ArgumentError : Class '<class 'models.User'>' already has a primary mapper defined. Use non_primary=True to create a non primary Mapper.  clear_mappers() will remove *all* current mappers from all classes."}
```

Собственно не понимаю почему, и чего от меня требуют.

Код:

```
from models import User
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker


def test():
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database.db', echo=True)
    metadata = MetaData()
    users_table = Table('users', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('name', String),
        Column('fullname', String),
        Column('password', String)
    )

    metadata.create_all(engine)

    mapper(User, users_table)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    vasiaUser = User("Вася", "Василий", "qweasdzxc")
    return session.add(vasiaUser)


if __name__ == "main":
    test()
```

> P.S. Пусть вас не пугает `if __name__ == "main":` вызов происходит из
>   под Pythonnet из файла main.py

Answer (score 0):

Не особо понял, зачем вам mapper. И не увидел ваш User.
Предлагаю вам решение с наследованием. Что бы вынести в файл достаточно перенести туда класс User, и вверху сделать импорт из главного файла(где инициализируются подключение) db.

А вообще переезжайте на ручное создание таблиц с помощью Alembic и ручных запросов с помощью SQLAlchemy(без использования ORM).

```
import os
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, Column, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker


class Config:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get(
        "DATABASE_URL"
    ) or "sqlite:///" + os.path.join(
        os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "app.db"
    )


db = declarative_base()


class User(db):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(String(256), default=None)


engine = create_engine(Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

db.metadata.create_all(engine)  # CREATE

vasiaUser = User(name="Василий")
session.add(vasiaUser)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Вообще я ручным mysql 15 лет пользуюсь, и orm нужна для быстрой разработки своих утилит а не для продакшена. Проверю завтра.

Comment: Я сам не особо понял что и зачем, изучать только начал работу с этой библиотекой, по этому документу делал. https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQLAlchemy

Comment: По ссылке написан декларативный стиль, про него читайте, а уже потом научитесь соединять, если потребуется. С Alembic так же пишется модель(как тут User) с помощью metadata генерируется новая версия скрипта для создания таблиц(далее для миграции). После этого в этом скрипте можно внести изменения в случае ошибок при автоматической генерации. Далее этот скрип запускается и автоматический создается база(или мигрирует). Через SQLAlchemy удобно строить запросы по этой же модели. Пример: sqlalchemy.select([cls.id, cls.name]).where(cls.name == name). Такое не только для продакшена.

Comment: Как правильно вынести класс в User в отдельный файл чтобы ваш код работал?

Comment: Этот файла по сути __init__.py. Класс User выносите в отдельный файл например model.py (внутри нужные импорты делаете). В __init__.py на месте User пишите from model import User. С config так же, можно через наследование использовать Enum, можете убрать. В большом проекте придется делать. И дальше любые фреймворки запускаете в __init__.py. И в них(где нужна база) передаете уже db. Внутри других файлов(реализации на фреймворка) так же User импортируете(где надо).